# Joining two models with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I currently have a `Subscriber` model and a `Comment` model. The `Subscriber` has_many `comments` and the `comment` belongs_to `Subscriber`. All I want is for a Subscriber to be able to make a comment in a text field and that comment belongs to that Subscriber through an id. For some reason I can't not figure this out and I'm having a tough time getting help. So, to be very clear I have a `subscriber_id` on the `comment` model, how do I attach them together so that I can make this call in the Rails Console - `@comment = @subscriber.comments.first` and see the first comment that belongs to that particular subscriber? I'll show some code for clarity.

SCHEMA:

```
         create_table "comments", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "description"
t.datetime "created_at",    null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",    null: false
t.string   "fav_drink"
t.string   "visit_time"
t.integer  "subscriber_id"
end

create_table "subscribers", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "first_name"
t.string   "last_name"
t.string   "email"
t.string   "phone_number"
t.string   "birthdate"
t.string   "street_1"
t.string   "street_2"
t.string   "city"
t.string   "zip"
t.string   "state"
t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
t.integer  "visit"
end
```

CONTROLLERS:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
def new
  @comment = Comment.new
end

def create
  @comment = Comment.create(comments_params)
  if @comment.save
    flash[:notice] = "Thank you!"
    redirect_to subscribers_search_path(:comments)
  else
    render "new"
  end
end

private

def comments_params
  params.require(:comment).permit(:fav_drink, :subscriber_id)
end
end



class SubscribersController < ApplicationController
 def index
  @subscriber = Subscriber.all
 end

 def new
  @subscriber = Subscriber.new
end

def create
  @subscriber = Subscriber.create(subscriber_params)
  if @subscriber.save
    flash[:notice] = "Subscriber Has Been Successfully Created"
    redirect_to new_subscriber_path(:subscriber)
  else
    render "new"
  end
end
```

And the Models are as described in the intro. Thank You!

Comment: unless I'm missing something, this looks like a standard `has_many` relationship.  If it's not working as you expected, you'll need to include the code for the models too.

Comment: Yes it is. Maybe I'm missing something then, but I can't figure out how to link the two. right now if I leave a comment in the text field I set up in the view I'll have that comment sure, but I will not be attached to any particular subscriber. That is what I want for the comment to actually belong to someone. I have trouble asking this question cause I really am lost to the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple approaches:

**Approach 1: Using current_user/ logged_in user**

If the subscriber is supposedly logged into the system,
and if the current_user is the reference to the logged_in
subscriber, then you could assign the current_user to the
comment before creating.

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @comment = Comment.new
  end

  def create
    @comment = current_user.comments.build(comments_params)

    if @comment.save
      flash[:notice] = "Thank you!"
      redirect_to subscribers_search_path(:comments)
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end

  private

  def comments_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:fav_drink)
  end
end
```

**Approach 2: Hidden Field**

Set a subscriber_id hidden_field in the comments form and then
your existing implementation should work fine. Just for clarify
I am copy/pasting your implementation.

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @comment = Comment.new
  end

  def create
    @comment = Comment.new(comments_params)

    if @comment.save
      flash[:notice] = "Thank you!"
      redirect_to subscribers_search_path(:comments)
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end

  private

  def comments_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:fav_drink, :subscriber_id)
  end
end
```

**Approach 3: Nested Resource**

Using the `rails` nested resource, set your routes to the following:

```
resources :subscribers
  resources: comments, only: [:new, :create]
end
```

Then update your controller code to the following:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @comment = Comment.new
  end

  def create
    @subscriber = Subscriber.find(params[:subscriber_id])
    @comment = @subscriber.comments.build(comments_params)

    if @comment.save
      flash[:notice] = "Thank you!"
      redirect_to subscribers_search_path(:comments)
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end

  private

  def comments_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:fav_drink)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'm going with number 3 but I'm getting an error when I try to implement. `Couldn't find Subscriber with 'id'=` Any Idea why I'm getting this error?

Comment: Check whats the value of `params[:subscriber_id]` that is being received to the `create` action.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of going about this. I'd highlight 3 below:

1. Use a nested resource routes, for example:

   resources :subscribers do
     resources :comments
   end

Using this approach your routes would become subscribers/1/comments... and in your comments_controller, you can fetch your subscriber from `params[:subscriber_id]`

2. If the subscriber is the current_user, you could as well set it in your comments_controller as such:

   `current_user.comments.create(comments_params)`
3. Use a hidden field in your `comments/form` to set the subscriber.

Basically, looking at your `comments_params`, you're requiring the `subscriber_id`, which is not being passed to the controller. So you need a way of passing this down.

You could set your subscriber before the `create/new` action and then do:

`@subscriber.comments.[create|new]` then in your `new` comments form view, you would have `f.hidden_field :subscriber_id`

Let me know if that works.

Comment: It's not a current_user so the option that I like the most is number 3. I'm new to rails and I have not coded a hidden field yet. Anyway you could elaborate/example what that would look like in my case?

Comment: Yeah, basically within your `form_for` block, you would have a `f.hidden_field :subscriber_id`. However, I'd be a bit curious as to how who your subscriber would be. Is it a user? How would the user be fetched or created etc? You need a way to keep track of the subscriber, that's why the nested resource may also make sense, which wouldn't require the subscriber but the subscriber would be fetched from the route